# Present Perfect + Adverb

Tags: present-perfect, adverbs

What is the correct form of this sentence:

"**I have bought another product meanwhile**"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What is the correct form of this sentence:

> "I have bought another product meanwhile"?

Here are some alternatives:

"In the meantime, I have bought another product."

"I have bought another product, in the meantime."

"While I was forced to wait, I bought another product."

"While you delayed the order, I bought another product."

With "meanwhile", you could re-order it like this:

"Meanwhile, I have bought another product."

However, there is something about this word...  It seems to be more appropriate for describing distant actions, and actions by others, in a story.  When talking about yourself and your own decisions, "while" and "meantime" seem a bit better.

A narrator in a novel might say "Meanwhile, in another part of Gotham..."

Answer (score 0):

I think the verb tense is irrelevant here. The same answer would probably apply if other verb tenses were used.

What is relevant is the positioning of the adverb. The routine place for adverbs (or adverbial phrases) is at the end of sentences. However, if the meaning of the adverb is important to the sentence they tend to be promoted to earlier positions.

In your sentence, 'meanwhile' **is important** to the meaning. The message of the sentence seems to be, "I couldn't wait any longer, so I did something else."

The two positions the adverb could be promoted to are to the start of the sentence or between the 'have' and 'bought' of the verb phrase.

Your version is not ungrammatical but it is not what most people would say. They would tend to say either:

> Meanwhile, I have bought another product.

or (but this would be less common)

> I have meanwhile bought another product.